# Move Focus From PasswordEditField to Next PasswordEditField in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I am new to BlackBerry and Java. I am trying to figure out but not getting any correct way to implemnt my task. I want to enter 16 digit password. So for that, I have four passwordEditField in HorizontalFieldManager, each passwordEditField allows max 4 digits. When I enter 4 digits in first leftmost passwordEditField, I want to set focus automatically to the following next passwordEditField without any keypress. I used,

```
passwordEditField = new PasswordEditField("","",4,0){

     protected void onUnfocus()
     {
         this.setFocus(passwordEditField.getIndex()+1,0,0);
     }

};
```

I tried moveFocus(), setFocus(), setCursorPosition() but not getting the focus on to next element. Is there any way i can impelement this task in blackberry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
passwordEditField.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {
    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
        String text = passwordEditField.getText().toString();
        if (text.length() == 4) {
            nextPasswordEditField.setFocus();
        }
    }
});
```